# Recursive vs iterative factorials in java?

Tags: java, recursion, factorial, iteration

In java, which method is typically faster for computing the factorials of numbers? Recursive or iterative?

Also, which works better for larger numbers and which is better for smaller numbers?

Comment: Iterative is always faster.

Comment: Why don't you try it.

Comment: At some point stack will overflow; you need to consider iterative approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative is always faster! And saver! And takes less memory!

When your working with recursive functions each step will be in your stack until the end which may take a lot resources.